# How can you hash an email address into a zero or one with relatively even distribution?

Tags: random

This may be a very stupid question - apologies in advance.

I'm wondering if it's possible to generate a random number from an email address.  I'm imagining something similar to how you can generate an md5 hash of an email address (or pretty much any string for that matter).

So basically such a function would allow you to generate the same random number from the same email address every time you ran it.

The application that I have in mind is to slot email addresses into an A/B test randomly.  Normally the way that you would implement such a thing would be to just generate a random number for each email address and store that along with the email address in order to tag a given email as belonging to A or B.

The nice thing about a function that could generate a random number from an email is that you wouldn't have to store that association anywhere.  You could run it on the fly to determine at any given time which bucket the email should fall into.

UPDATE: What I'm looking for is a hash, not a random number.  So it's just a matter of figuring out how to go from something like an MD5 hash to an integer with a value of 0 or 1.

UPDATE 2: Thanks for the answers and nudging me in the right direction.  So one solution in MYSQL is simply:

```
ASCII(SUBSTR(MD5(CONCAT(customer_email, 'salt')), 1, 1)) % 2
```

Comment: An arbitrary number or string generated from some meaningful data is called a _hash_. MD5 is a hash. You can use any hash that you can find.

Answer (score 2):

Yes a *Hash* by definition does this ( or it appears to ) create a someone random value given some string. But note that it's not really random. To deal with this we do a *salted hash*, which is to do a Hash that has a random number appended to it, then store both the salted hash with the random number. And it will give you the same results (as long as you retrieved the corresponding random number that the email was stored with).

Comment: Right, a hash not a random number.  So how would one go about generating a relatively evenly distributed random number from a hash though?

Comment: @kalenjordan You still do a hash, but to make it more random we concatenate a random number to the email address and then hash it, and each email has it's own random number that goes with it. In this way it will give a good random output, and not just a normal hash (this is called a salted hash). In a database, for example, we store the hash and the random number with it.

Comment: A salt is not to make a hash "more random". It's to prevent dictionary attacks. A good hash will have good distribution all by itself.

Comment: @JimCote Yes I understand that. But a hash by itself, for example an MD5 hash, if we know the input to the hash we can get the output, in other-words it's determined. A salted hash does indeed prevent dictionary attacks, but it also can make more random in the sense for the same input, we can have different outputs. By "more random" I mean it's no longer determinable (considering the salt is not known). *Note* I answered this question before the changes from the edit.

Answer (score 1):

When generated random number is same every time, it is no longer a random number. You can use ascii coding of characters used in the email for your random number. But there is a catch here : abc@xyz.com will be same as cba@xyz.com. So you have to take care of this somehow. Things will become complex if more special characters are used like _ or a dot(.) . Why can't we use the email itself as KEY.

Comment: Ah that's an interesting idea.  So you mean like adding up the ASCII values of the characters and then maybe taking that modulo 2 in order to "randomly" bucket an email into A or B?